# using entity framework 5.0 with sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I want to use entity framework 5.0 with sharepoint 2013. When I deploy a simple web part I get  "entity framework 5 could not load file or assembly entityframework version 5.0" error.

Can I use entity framework with sharepoint 2013? If so what is the problem?

Thank you.

Note:I can use ef5 in web projects, in addition I have another machine setted up sp2010 and entity  framework 4.0. They work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a work around and use WCF services to connect database.

Answer (score 0):

on the package manifest add the entity framework to the safe controls, this will add the safe control in the web.config of the corresponding sharepoint web application.